# How to call Soap service in Sap Cloud Sdk for javacript project Or Cap node.js project

Tags: soap

As the title mentioned, do I have any way to call soap service in sap cloud sdk for javascript or in cap node.js project?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oFlZ.png)

In Feature Matrix at sap.github.io as the pitcure show, Soap is not supported in cloud sdk for js.I don't know if it is also not supported in cap node.js.
is there any scheme to call soap service in these two scenes?(cap node.js will be better)
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call SOAP API's from SAP CAP,
please check [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/04/11/consuming-soap-web-services-in-sap-cloud-application-programming-model-cap/) blog post.